# Nest dll for framework 3.5

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
                defaultIndex: "documents"
                );
            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

I was trying to use nest with my project (framework 3.5) but it's not working, please I need the Dll that the support this framework version.

Best,

Comment: I am also looking for same.Any success Kamel?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in the NuGet feed, there is no version of NEST that supports .NET 3.5.